# div inside div with image

Tags: css, html

Quite simple, but it's driving-me crazy

I have a div inside a div that has an image inside and I need to align that child div on the right bottom corner ( later I will reproduce the same but to align the div in any of the four corners of the div).

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="someimage.jpg" />
    <div class="child">
        <b>Hi there !</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent div and the image have the same dimensions (900w x 300h) and the child div is 100w x 50h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to *absolutely* position the div to the bottom right of the parent div.

```
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqha4/)

For the other corners, you can set `left` and `top` positions as well.